# Geometry problem involving angular bisectors

Tags: geometry

ABC is a triangle.Let angle bisectors of $\angle B$ and $\angle C$ intersect at $O$.Drop perpendiculars from A to these bisectors.Join the foot of bisectors.We have to prove that this line is parallel to the base

I tried angle chasing and tried  to use Thales theorem but it is of no use .Can you help me out

Answer (score 0):

Let the angle bisectors meet at $I$ (relabelling your notation, since this is the incenter).
Let the perpendiculars from $A$ to the angle bisectors at $B$ and $C$ be $P$ and $Q$ respectively.

**Obvious Hint:**
$QP \parallel BC \Leftrightarrow \gamma / 2 = \angle IQP $

> **Further hint:** Show that $ \gamma / 2 =  \angle IAP $ and $ \angle IAP = \angle IQP$.

$ $

> The first is true by angle chasing.
>  The second is true because APIQ is a cyclic quad.

Comment: Angle chasing is the part where I am struck.

Comment: Just label everything. E.g. Can you find what is $\angle CAP$? What about $ \angle CAI$? Hence, what is $\angle IAP$?

Comment: Oh..I got it thanks

Comment: Side note: Be careful with your drawing - Making assumptions of whether $P, Q$ lie inside or outside of the triangle. In this case, it's much better to work with directed angles (else work with cases).